# replacing pixel value of one channel based on values of other two channels

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

`target_positive_replace = np.where(positive_replace[...,0]>0 or positive_replace[...,1]>0 or positive_replace[...,2]>0),target_positive_replace[...,1]=255 ,0)`

I have a three-channel RGB image.

Want to perform above operation.

if one of the given values in a channel is greater than zero (channel value>0). I want to make that pixel green. (0,255,0).

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: When you post code, make sure it is a [mre]. And when you post an error message, make sure you copy-paste the complete thing, including stack traces and so on. With the little information you give here, it’s harder to see what is wrong than necessary.

Comment: That said, `or` expects a single value on either side.  Combine Boolean arrays, use `|`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `positive_replace[...,x]` returns an array which cannot be checked with `>0`(**wrong**). So as the Error Message states you can either check each element of the returned array with `a.all()` or `a.any()` or you have to make sure to retreive the integer color value.

**Edit**

The above is only partially true. As @Cris Luengo states in his comment `or` expects a single value, not an array. So either compare single values with `a.all()` and `a.any()` or compare the boolean array returned by `positive_replace[...,x]>0` with `|`

Comment: `target_positive_replace[np.where ( ((target_positive_replace[...,0]>0).all(axis=0)) or ((target_positive_replace[...,2]>0).all(axis=2)))]=[0,255,0]`

Comment: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: The above code give that value errror

Comment: `target_positive_replace = np.where(((target_positive_replace[...,0]>0).any() or (target_positive_replace[...,1]>0).any() or (target_positive_replace[...,2]>0).any())
                                             ,target_positive_replace[...,1],0)`  *This Works Thanks for your time Zeg du Toit*

Comment: `target_positive_replace[...,0].all()>0`

Comment: @EVision if you're satisfied with the answer please consider marking it as "accepted"

Comment: You can compare an array with `>0`, this is not the issue.